# Get the common id of several collection in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have several collections of users in Mongodb. As below:

```
userCollection1:
User1: {name:xxx,
id:xxx
<other fields>}

User2: {name:xxx,
id:xxx
<other fields>}

..other users..

userCollection2:
User1: {name:xxx,
id:xxx
<other fields>}

User3: {name:xxx,
id:xxx
<other fields>}

..other users..

userCollection3:{}  //All same scheme as previous collection
userCollection4:{}
userCollection5:{}
```

Each is a separate collection of different lists of users.
Now I am trying to get the users that exist in all of these 5 collections.

One way I can think of is for loop.

> For each user in collection1,
>
> Query his id or name in collection 2, 3, 4, 5.
>
> if the id is in all of the collections, record his id.
>
> Otherwise, skip.
>
> Then go to the next user.

I feel this method isn't very efficient. There might be some better way using the mongodb aggregate method.

Any suggestion on this situation? Or I should just use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are searching for a common user in all 5 collections, we will query on user 1 collection and use the $lookup and join all other 4 collections. Here is the query suggestion which will definitely work.

All users collection has the same schema as above you mentioned: name and work field.

```
db.getCollection('user1').aggregate({ "$facet": { "presentInAllCollections": [{ "$lookup": { "from": "user2", "localField": "name", "foreignField": "name", "as": "User2" } }, { "$lookup": { "from": "user3", "localField": "name", "foreignField": "name", "as": "User3" } }, { "$lookup": { "from": "user4", "localField": "name", "foreignField": "name", "as": "User4" } }, { "$lookup": { "from": "user5", "localField": "name", "foreignField": "name", "as": "User5" } }] } }, { $project: { "foundUser": { $filter: { input: '$presentInAllCollections', as: 'arrayElement', cond: { "$and": [{ $ne: ['$$arrayElement.User2', []] }, { $ne: ['$$arrayElement.User3', []] }, { $ne: ['$$arrayElement.User4', []] }, { $ne: ['$$arrayElement.User5', []] } ] } } } } })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can join all 5 user collections to get the common user ids. For this you have to use $lookup function from aggregation pipeline.

```
userCollection1.aggregate([{
  $lookup:{
    from:"userCollection2", 
    localField:"id", 
    foreignField:"id",
    as:"alias_name"
     }
   }
 ]
)
```

This will return all the matching documents from both the collections.